# Convexity of a function defined in Artin's book

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The question I came to is not too technical. In the book Gamma Function by E. Artin, author starts as:

Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function.

For any $x_1,x_2\in (a,b)$ define quotient
$$
\varphi(x_1,x_2)=\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}=\varphi(x_2,x_1).
$$
For distinct $x_1,x_2,x_3\in (a,b)$, define
$$
\Psi(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{\varphi(x_1,x_3)-\varphi(x_2,x_3)}{x_1-x_2}.
$$
$f(x)$ is said to be convex on $(a,b)$ if for any $x_3$, $\varphi(x_1,x_3)$ is monotonically increasing function of $x_1$; this is equivalent to [by some reason] $\Psi(x_1,x_2,x_3)\ge 0$.

I do not understand one (non-technical) point:

> To talk about convexity of single function $f$, why Artin is going into more functions as $\varphi$ and $\Psi$?

(I tried to express the above quantities geometrically, but only $\varphi(x_1,x_2)$  realized to me as slope of a line but I not realized $\Psi(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. )

Comment: Take this with a pinch of salt, but if I were to guess, it might be that the author is trying to appeal to the first-order (tangent lines) and second-order (second derivatives) characterisation of convexity.

Answer (score 1):

For a function $f \in \mathcal C^2(a, b)$, there's a well-known result that states that $f$ is convex if an only if it's second derivative $f''$ is $\geq 0$ on $(a, b)$. It comes from the fact that $f$ is convex if and only if $f'$ is monotonically increasing (this is the same idea than saying that its slopes are increasing), and well, $f'$ is monotonically increasing if and only if $f''$ is $\geq 0$.

This is the same idea here, the function $\psi$ is sort of "the slopes of the slopes". So the fact that $\psi$ is $\geq 0$ will imply that $\varphi$ is monotonically increasing in $x_1$ and thus that $f$ is convex.